# crop an image into a circle rmagick + rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, rmagick

I am a newbie to RoR and for a feature we need to resize and crop images into circular/oval shaped images. I am using Carrierwave gem to upload them and rmagick(2.1.2) to modify the images on rails 4.1 platform.

On top of that, we need to dynamically mask the images with some color(saved in the modal, every image would have different color based on certain parametes.) before rendering them.

For the first part, I am trying this:

```
def crop_large
  manipulate! do |source|
    source = source.resize_to_fill(450,450).quantize(256,Magick::GRAYColorspace).contrast(true)

    canvas = Magick::Image.new 450,450
    gc = Magick::Draw.new
    gc.fill "black"
    gc.circle 225,225,5,225
    gc.draw canvas

    mask = canvas.blur_image(0,1).negate

    mask.matte = false
    source.matte = true
    source.composite!(mask, Magick::CenterGravity, Magick::MultiplyCompositeOp)
  end
end
```

But this leaves black borders and I don't know how to get rid of them. Any clues on how should I fix this?

Also, I don't know how to get the 2nd part done.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are having styling issues, fix it with css by adding a class or two,
it will be much easier.